# How to import a .csv file into ADS?

Tags: ads

I'm using ADS2006A version and I'm trying to plot an eye diagram. However, I need to import a .csv file into ADS first because I did the simulation in Matlab. While importing, it asks for pattern length and point/bit. I tried putting several values but did not manage to get the simulation that I want. Can I know what pattern length and point/bit refers to?

Comment: Speak to Keysight about this first.

Comment: Edit the file and see it shows in front